# Why executing an archive in command line doesn't automatically use binary to open it like on Windows?

Tags: shell

Trying in command line to open an archive on Windows opens the associated program for the file extension without questions, for example, using this command would open the archive with my default archive manager supporting .rar files.

```
 $env:temp/SuperArchive.rar
```

Why on Linux, I cannot open an archive, or extract it just by using a similar command, as

```
~/tmp/SuperArchive.tar.gz
```

Comment: You can: Use `xdg-open <file>` and the file opens with the default application for that file type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to a design difference between Windows and Unix regarding the approach to loading programs. Unix is primarily application-centric: you run an application, and in the application, you open some files. Windows is primarily document-centric (in this respect): you open a document, and Windows chooses the application for you.

Both models have their upsides and downsides. The Windows is a little easier to use sometimes… until you want to open a document in a non-default application. Or you just wanted to see what's inside the archive. Or you wanted to extract the archive in a different directory. Or you wanted to create a new document in the current directory. Graphical file managers on Unix implement a document-centric model.

Somewhat related to this design decision, Unix makes applications easier to reach: all executables are installed in a handful of directories that are on the command search path, so you can invoke an application from the command line by typing the name of the executable. For example, to open an archive in Ark, run `ark myarchive.tar.gz`. The system often helps you by completing only file names that make sense for this particular application.

You can run the [`xdg-open`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open) command to open a file in a system-chosen application. For a `.tar.gz` file, this is likely to invoke a graphical archive manager; which program is invoked depends on what programs you have installed and on your graphical environment.

Comment: So far, the most complete answer

Answer (score 4):

Binary applications and scripts with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) are executable. A `.gz` file is not executable and you need a program to open it.

When the `xdg-utils` are installed you can open the file with the associated program:

```
xdg-open <file>
```

Comment: See also `man 1 open` and `man xdg-mime` for configuring what the "associated program" is.

Answer (score 0):

The original meaning of tar was **T**ape **AR**chiver.

You would use it like

```
tar cf /dev/rmt0 dir1 dir2
```

which would put `dir1` and `dir2`'s contents on whatever tape in local drive `/dev/rmt0`.

File would be read using

```
tar xf /dev/rmt0 dir2
```

to extract only `dir2` from local tape.

In the unix philosophy, you could archive to a file, or a pipe, e.g.

```
tar cf - foo | ( ssh remote  "cd /distant ; tar xf - ")
```

- to transfert from local to /distant dir in remote host

or

```
tar cf project.tar foo
```

and mail project.tar to someone.

So tar was never meant to be self extractable. The closest thing in unix was shar (shell archiver), which was almost doing it. You would receive a file called `project.shar`, then run

```
sh project.shar
```

which would deflate file on local dir (and bring some security risk by the way).

Comment: The question as asked is not talking about self-extracting archives.  It is talking about file type associations mapping from the `.rar` extension to the user's chosen archive manager program which [(in conjunction with `PATHEXT` if one wants to eliminate the explicit extension) can be used to make data files executable as commands in Microsoft's command interpreter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb490912.aspx).

Comment: agreed, I tought your way latter on, and was wondering about a new answer or an edit, but i failed to write a clear answer ( no .exe on linux ).

Answer (score -1):

Self extracting archives need a binary component and a binary component from a non-standard execution enviroment like `Win-DOS` will not work on a standard execution environment like UNIX.

Also note that UNIX is a source code standard so UNIX does not specify a unique binary standard.

There have been self extracting archives on UNIX (called `shell archies`), but these archives have the disadvantage that they cannot give a decent compression.

Comment: This is not related to the question as asked, which describes a RAR file being opened through [an association of the user's chosen archive manager to the RAR file type](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/ff687021.aspx) and is not talking about self-extracting archives.